# Handling of forward/back slashes by Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scp

I have been reading that Windows Powershell is slash direction agnostic, in that it can take both forward/back slashes for file paths.

For some reason, when transferring files between my Windows laptop and HPC cluster (linux), I was under the assumption that I had to convert all forward slashes (/) used in linux to backslashes (\) in my Powershell commands.

For example, if the file on HPC cluster was on /path/file, I would do scp \path\file \path\destination.

Clearly, it has been working(?) but I was wondering how Windows Powershell knew to "convert" my backslashes (\) to forward slashes (/) when accessing the linux location, as on linux forward slashes (/) are used for file paths.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think it shows that powershell handles both forward and backslahes. My question was more related to how powershell/openssh/scp knows to translate my erroneously used backslashes for remote linux server file path into forward slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell does not "know" that there is a Linux computer on the other
side. The fact that the copy works means that PowerShell uses a
copy method that avoids the need for knowing that.

It's only an (educated) guess, but the method would be to descend
sub-folder by sub-folder until the final sub-folder.

For `\path\file \path\destination`, PowerShell would position itself
to `\path`, then to `destination`, and finally will copy the file to it.
This way it can stay slash-agnostic across differing operating systems.